# Convert CGPoint array to String in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I have array of points like:

```
[(32.33332824707031, 237.0), (105.33332824707031, 355.3333282470703), (124.0, 355.3333282470703), (165.3333282470703, 240.0), (116.33332824707031, 199.66665649414062)]
```

I created a dictionary out of this array as

```
let dic : Dictionary<String, [CGPoint]> = [ "ARRAY" : points]
```

I create a jsondata to create a json string as below

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

But i am getting error as:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write
>   (NSConcreteValue)'.

Comment: is this solves your purpose: let dic : Dictionary<String, [[Double]]> = [ "ARRAY" : [[32.33332824707031, 237.0], [105.33332824707031, 355.3333282470703], [124.0, 355.3333282470703], [165.3333282470703, 240.0], [116.33332824707031, 199.66665649414062]]]
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted)

Comment: your `points` is of type `[(Double, Double)]`. not `[CGPoint]` .

Answer (score 2):

Tuples aren't codable but CGPoint is so either keep your original CGPoint array if you have one or map the array from tuple to CGPoint

```
let points = array.map {CGPoint(x: $0.0, y: $0.1)}

let dic : Dictionary<String, [CGPoint]> = [ "ARRAY" : points]
do {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

    let data = try encoder.encode(dic)
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: it worked well. Thanks. What is the reason JSONEncoder works in this case but JSONSerialization.data doesn't work and throws error.

Comment: @ctoplatform Because I am making use of `Codable` protocol that CGPoint conforms to, With JSONSerialization you can only use basic types, see [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization). I guess with JSONSerialization  you would have to convert each tuple into an array instead, so in my opinion this is a better solution.